# Create a second border in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple white button that has a border around it. You can find the code below.

```css
.checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    border: solid #5a4ef5 3px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: white;
    color: #5a4ef5;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
    <input id="switch-1" type="checkbox" value={props.value} class="visually-hidden"/>
    <label htmlFor="switch-1" class="switch-label checkbox-label text-center">TEST</label>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/pocockn/pen/RwopVLz

This was super simple to do however I want to add a second border to give it a more 3D feel.

Like this:

[image: button]

I'm struggling to work out how to do with this pure CSS, I'm thinking I could create the button in Photoshop and use an image but I'm not sure that will then work with a responsive web page.

Is this possible with pure CSS? Or is a button image my only option?

And then on mobile I'd like for the "3D" border to disappear and be left with what I currently have.

Answer (score -2):

you Might wanna put the button inside a `div` and than give a `div` a padding inside so the button can go inside and then creat a border for the `div`